# how to generate token after installing reposilite using docker

Tags: docker, maven, repository, maven-central

I am new in installing reposilite. I am trying to use this repository tool for our team. we are using java based application development.

When installing reposilite using docker command, the installation run smoothly and I can see the dashboard. But found that it is required a token (user name and password) for login into the system.

In the documentation, I can't find anywhere which describe the steps for creating token after installing through docker.  (Or I am missing something in the documentation.)

Can anyone please suggest, how to create a token in reposilite (docker).

Thanks

Comment: https://reposilite.com/guide/tokens ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, tokens in Reposilite are generated through CLI with [`token-generate`](https://reposilite.com/guide/tokens#generating-token) command. By default, that's slightly problematic in Docker, so there are 2 options:

1. Run Docker image with [interactive terminal (`-it`)](https://reposilite.com/guide/docker), so you can use Reposilite's command line
2. Use [temporary token](https://reposilite.com/guide/tokens#temporary-tokens) to bootstrap permission system through [`REPOSILITE_OPTS`](https://reposilite.com/guide/docker#reposilite-properties) env variable

If you use Docker Compose, there's a dedicated section in Reposilite's guide for it:

- https://reposilite.com/guide/docker#using-docker-compose